# Virtual TCP socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, opendaylight

I have an application that provides TCP-packets **as objects**. I can also send TCP-packets into the network using the same object representation.
I can also easily get the byte[] representation of the TCP-packets.

Since i do not want to implement the TCP stack myself:

**Is there a library that would act as a "virtual" socket?**

The requirements would be something like this:

- Socket behaves like a normal socket would on the frontend
- On the backend i feed in / take out TCP-packets (in any format, e.g. as byte[])

If it matters, the application is an SDN controller (Opendaylight in particular).

Comment: Your description is rather vague.

Comment: Presumably you have an operating system underneath your application, so you don't need to implement a TCP/IP stack. The common approach is to just use the loopback interface for this (normally the IP address 127.0.0.1). Your frontend just connects to a particular port on the loopback interface, the server listens to that port (your backend). If you want the packets to eventually reach a real network though, you might want a virtual interface instead (e.g. a TUN/TAP interface in linux terms). Or since this is java, you could perhaps just subclass a a java.net.Socket.